# GatsbyJS + GraphQL - Error when query with "edges", Could anybody please explain this query error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I've got an error when I query using "useStaticQuery" in "GatsbyJS" as the following code:

```
const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query ExperienceQuery {
    allExperienceJson {
      edges {
        node {
            src
            desc
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);
```

[image]

but when I remove "edges", it works properly.

```
const Experience = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query ExperienceQuery {
    allExperienceJson {
      nodes {
          src
          desc
        }
      }
    }
  `);
```

Could anybody please explain this query error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could anybody please explain this query error?

`edges` and `node`(`s`) are both children of the main GraphQL node. Assuming you're using [`gatsby-transformer-json`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-transformer-json/) to source your `allExperience` from a JSON, according to the docs it should create both nodes (`edges` and `node`).

However, depending on your Gatsby version (since it's an official plugin) it may be creating `nodes` node directly, which in fact it's the same as doing `edges.nodes` (in terms that `node`(`s`) always holds the array of data). If your Gatsby version is creating a structure of `allExperienceJson.nodes` and you are trying to get `allExperienceJson.edges.node` your code will break.

In your case, if the second approach works, I would leave it as is. However, double-check the query in the GraphiQL playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`) because you may be facing some rehydration issues. You should always use the query that you tested in the GraphiQL environment.

For example: if the first query works in the GraphiQL playground, but the code fails, you are facing a rehydration issue, which means that at the time you are trying to get `allExperience` it's not filled hence the `.slice` fails. If that's the case, add a safeguard (check if the data is different from `null` before the slice) or use the nullish coalescent operator (`?`):

```
const allExperience = data.allExperienceJson?.edges?.node ?? []
```

In that way are bypassing a potential `null` data fetch at a glance (avoiding the code to break) because of the `[]` assignation and when the query is rehydrated `allExperience` should contain the correct data.

If the second query is the one that works in the GraphiQL playground, forget what I said and go through using it.

Comment: It's very clear.